# Why would a modal button have to be clicked twice to post to a form?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 modal pop up then I have to click the Delete button twice for it to work.  My other modals don't do this, but wasn't sure what I may have done in the jquery code to cause this?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
//[delete] button
$('#delete_questions1').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var btn = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var questionID = btn.data('mylink1');  //calls in bootstrap data-mylink1=\"$row[questionID]\"
    var auditID = btn.data('mylink2');  //calls in bootstrap data-mylink2=\"$row[auditID]\"

    $('#deletequestion').text(auditID);//links auditID to our input button
    $('#deletequestion').text(questionID);  //links questionID to our input button
    $('#deletequestion').click(function() {
        //alert("edit_questions.php?action=delete&questionID="+questionID+"&auditID="+auditID); //testing button
        $.post("edit_questions.php?action=delete&questionID="+questionID+"&auditID="+auditID, function(data) {
            if(data) {
                //alert(data);
                alert('You have successfully DELETED the quesiton for this audit.');
            window.location.reload(true);
            }
        });//End post 
    }); 

        var button_text=$(this).attr("value");
        if(button_text=="Restore"){
            var title1="Restore Question";
            var msg="You have selected to <strong>RESTORE</strong> this question. Are you sure thats what you want to do?";
        }else{
            var title1="Delete Question";
            var msg="Are you sure you want to <strong>DELETE</strong> this question? If the audit has NOT been published you will not be able to get it back.";
        }
            $('#DeleteQuestionTitle1').html(title1);
            $('#DeleteQuestionText1').html(msg);
    });//End Delete
}); //End Main JQuery Function      
</script>
```

Button for Modal to pop up:

```
                        <input 
                        data-mylink1=\"$row[questionID]\" 
                        data-mylink2=$auditID
                        type='button'
                        class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' role='button'                 
                        data-toggle='modal' 
                        data-target='#delete_questions1'
                        value=$edit_button />
```

Bootstrap 3 modal that pops up -- have to click delete button twice for it to work

```
                  <!-- modal pop up for [delete] button-->
<div class="modal" id="delete_questions1"  style="z-index:10000" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="DeleteQuestionTitle1"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="DeleteQuestionText1">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <form role="form" method = "POST">

                <input class="btn btn-default"  type="button" id="deletequestion" value='Delete' />

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>       
            </form> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the first click actually does what it's supposed to on the server-side? One click seems to work just fine if the AJAX request is taken out of the picture (e.g. `$post(" ", function(data)` ). See here: https://jsfiddle.net/mikehomme/s1z01czj/

Answer (score 0):

I commented this part out because it was redundant and now it does it in one click!

```
//  if(data) {
                //alert(data);
//  }
```